# ¿Diferencia entre Fwrite y Fputs?

Tags: php

Actualmente estoy programando una pequeña práctica en la que varios compañeros estamos usando el `fputs` y el `fwrite` en el que no parece que afecte el funcionamiento de la    practica (el cual yo estoy usando `fwrite`, fue el primero que usé), y me entró la duda de las diferencias de estos. Sería de mucha ayuda que me explicaran. Gracias

Comment: no hay diferencias, `fputs` es un alias de `fwrite` -> https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/d3ca28f5694e7848fb2b238bbe3e9564230ae65e/ext/standard/basic_functions.c#L3144

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si revisas [**`fputs`** en el Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/function.fputs.php) te darás cuenta de que es un alias de `fwrite`. Lo cual quiere decir que en realidad es la misma función:

> **`fputs`** — Alias de [`fwrite()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.fwrite.php)
>
> #### Descripción
>
> Esta función es un alias de: [`fwrite()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.fwrite.php).

PHP tiene varias casos parecidos, como viene explicado en el apartado [**Listado de funciones alias**](http://php.net/manual/es/aliases.php) :

> Hay unas cuantas funciones en PHP que se pueden llamar con más de un
>   nombre. En algunos de los casos no hay ningún nombre preferido de
>   entre los múltiples nombres, `is_int()` e `is_integer()` son un buen
>   ejemplo. Sin embargo hay funciones que cambiaron de nombre a causa de
>   una limpieza del API o alguna otra razón y los nombres antiguos solo
>   se preservan como alias para mantener la compatibilidad con versiones
>   anteriores. Suele ser mala idea usar este tipo de alias, ya que pueden
>   quedar obsoletos o que cambien de nombre, y hacer imposible la
>   portabilidad del script. Esta lista se facilita para ayudar a las
>   personas que quieren actualizar su código antiguo a una nueva
>   sintaxis.

Debemos buscar entonces el motivo por el que `fputs` es un alias, para saber si es preciso evitar su uso.

Veamos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando dice *Sintaxis de base*, significa que puedes usar cualquiera de las dos, porque el motivo del alias no es debido a salvar compatibilidad con otras librerías. De todos modos, un alias será siempre un alias. Yo usaría siempre el original.